how filter a dataframe to remove rows in which no column contains a value higher than X or lower than Y
I am trying to remove any rows of data that do not contain any values that are greater than 5 or less than -5 in order to exclude them from my data analysis.  I could not find a way to use an OR function within my filter command so I decided to create two new dataframes (one with only rows in which there is a value above 5 and one with only rows if there is a value below -5).  I then merge them together.  The problem is that some rows contain both a number greater than 5 and another less than -5 so when I use bind_rows the data gets entered twice into the new filtered dataframe.  I either need to bind the rows only if the row name is unique or find a way to filter the data without making two separate dataframes.
Here is my code:
Data <- read.table("C:/Users/Data.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, fill = TRUE)
row.names(Data) <- Data$gene

Data <- Data[, -1]

FilteredDataHigh <- Data %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ . >= 5))

FilteredDataLow <- Data %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ . <= -5))

FilteredData <- bind_rows(FilteredDataHigh, FilteredDataLow)



For "greater than 5 or less than -5" you'd need using > 5 and < -5 rather than >= 5 and <= -5. I also recommend trying data.table::fread('Data.txt'), which is much faster than read.table for large genomic data.

I think this should give your required result:
library(dplyr)
FilteredData <- Data %>%
    filter(if_any(everything(), function(x) x <= -5 | x >= 5))


We are interested in rows where any bound of absolute row ranges is above 5. We can use matrixStats::rowRanges and matrixStats::rowAnys for this task. (If you're working with Bioconductor, you can use MatrixGenerics::rowRanges and MatrixGenerics::rowAnys which are essentially the same.)
Consider this data
> dat
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
1 -4.4 -1.7 -5.1  4.4  1.2  1.3
2 -4.6 -2.2  4.1 -0.2 -2.0  0.7
3  2.3  0.4  0.3  1.2  5.3  4.9
4 -3.5 -2.3 -0.6 -4.3 -3.5 -5.0
5 -1.5 -4.6 -4.3  0.6  5.2  0.7
6 -0.2  2.6  3.8 -3.6  3.1 -4.9
7 -2.5  0.4 -5.2 -2.5 -4.3 -4.1
8  3.9 -4.7 -4.7 -3.3 -1.2 -1.5

We can generate a boolean,
> matrixStats::rowAnys(abs(matrixStats::rowRanges(as.matrix(dat))) > 5)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

and subset.
> dat[matrixStats::rowAnys(abs(matrixStats::rowRanges(as.matrix(dat))) > 5), ]
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
1 -4.4 -1.7 -5.1  4.4  1.2  1.3
3  2.3  0.4  0.3  1.2  5.3  4.9
5 -1.5 -4.6 -4.3  0.6  5.2  0.7
7 -2.5  0.4 -5.2 -2.5 -4.3 -4.1

It is even a bit faster if we use data.table.
data.table::setDT(dat)[matrixStats::rowAnys(abs(matrixStats::rowRanges(as.matrix(dat))) > 5)]

Benchmark
Run with a 10,000 x 100 matrix.
$ Rscript --vanilla foo.R
Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 matrixStats 2.161570 2.227393 2.541228 2.274809 2.366065 6.103258   100 a  
  data.table 1.705659 1.753344 1.958201 1.889855 1.938065 5.125560   100  b 
       dplyr 4.444964 4.679311 5.140791 4.941204 5.279537 9.848235   100   c


Data:
> set.seed(42)
> dat <- replicate(6, -runif(8, -5.3, 5.3)) |> round(1) |> as.data.frame()

